# Letting a background task finish before moving on in a loop

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, while-loop

I'm trying to run a background task (*query.findobjectinbackground* to be exact) inside a repeat loop. The catch is I need this to finish before moving on and running the loop again.

I need it to finish because in the background task an array is being populated that will eventually lead to a UITable being populated.

When I run it in its current state the loop runs through and finishes while the background task is still running.

Here's my code:

```
//array Im trying to populate
var contentArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func queryStatusTable() {
    contentArray.removeAllObjects()

    //query my table
    let queryUser = PFUser.query()
    let objectIdString = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
    queryUser?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectIdString!)
    queryUser?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {                    

                //used for the repeat loop 
                //object["userFriendsArray"] is an array I got from my above query 

                var i:Int = 0
                let count:Int = object["userFriendsArray"].count

                repeat {

                    //second query
                    let queryFriendStatus = PFQuery(className: "Content")
                    queryFriendStatus.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: object["userFriendsArray"][i])

                    //this is what I want to finish before the loop moves on
                    queryFriendStatus.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if let objects = objects {
                            for object in objects {
                                self.contentArray.addObject(object["content"])
                            }
                        }

                    })

                    //so i dont want this to run until the above task finishes
                    //and putting this inside the above task doesnt work because it will never run if its inside the findobjectinbackground
                    i++

                } while (i < count)
            }
        }

        //this is where I reload the table data to populate it with
        //whats in my *contentArray*
        self.firstTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

So how would I insure that *contentArray* is populated before *self.firstTableView.reloadData()* runs?

Any help would be apprectiated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not update your table periodically as you build up the data ?

It will give the user something to look at and will appear much faster.

I've done this before by calling the reload every 50 rows (or whatever) and then at the end, call it again to get the last rows

Remember to make the calls through the main queue from within your background data collection - like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.firstTableView.reloadData() 
}
```

Comment: You make a good point about loading one row at a time, but that wont help even if I change it. In my code the *self.firstTableView.reloadData()* is being called before my array is being populated so I need to figure out how to call the *self.firstTableView.reloadData()* after the array is populated. Which is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: provided you set the number of rows to match how much data you have already loaded, then you can make repeated calls to self.firstTableView.reloadData() and you will see the table being populated, while the rest of the data is loaded.  All you need then is some way of alerting the user that everything is complete - either an ActivityIndicator, or a message at the end.

You probably wouldn't want to update  every row - that will just slow it down, but you can update a page or two at a time

Comment: You're right about the very first reloadData - there won't be any data ready for that one - but you don't need it if you're refreshing throughout the load - and also once more at the end unless you have an exact multiple of your refresh interval!

Comment: Putting *self.firstTableView.reloadData()* under *self.contentArray.addObject(object["content"])* doesn't work. Where do you sugest I put it?

Comment: doesn't work? in what way?
If you're getting an error about updating the user interface from a background task, you should use the main queue - I have updated my answer to show what I mean